# HTML button can not overlap css background

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to show login form on the top of cloud bakground. I copy cloud backgroud script from [this link](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/pure-css3-animated-clouds-background) . In css .cloud I change position from relative to absolute but login form not move on the top of cloud.

This is my code I paste cloud backgroud script before login form.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /*To hide the horizontal scroller appearing during the animation*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

#clouds {
  padding: 100px 0;
  #background: #c9dbe9;
  #background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
  #background: -linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
  #background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
}


/*Time to finalise the cloud shape*/

.cloud {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 200px;
  -moz-border-radius: 200px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.cloud:before,
.cloud:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 10px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.cloud:after {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  top: -55px;
  left: auto;
  right: 15px;
}


/*Time to animate*/

.x1 {
  -webkit-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
}


/*variable speed, opacity, and position of clouds for realistic effect*/

.x2 {
  left: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
  opacity: 0.6;
  /*opacity proportional to the size*/
  /*Speed will also be proportional to the size and opacity*/
  /*More the speed. Less the time in 's' = seconds*/
  -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
}

.x3 {
  left: -250px;
  top: -200px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0.8;
  /*opacity proportional to the size*/
  -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

.x4 {
  left: 470px;
  top: -250px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
  transform: scale(0.75);
  opacity: 0.75;
  /*opacity proportional to the size*/
  -webkit-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
}

.x5 {
  left: -150px;
  top: -150px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0.8;
  /*opacity proportional to the size*/
  -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
  0% {
    margin-left: 1000px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1000px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
  0% {
    margin-left: 1000px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1000px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
  0% {
    margin-left: 1000px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="clouds">
  <div class="cloud x1"></div>
  <!-- Time for multiple clouds to dance around -->
  <div class="cloud x2"></div>
  <div class="cloud x3"></div>
  <div class="cloud x4"></div>
  <div class="cloud x5"></div>
</div>

<!-- ************  This is my login form  ************ -->
<div id="authloginContainer">
  <div class="authloginTabContent" authpluginarray="1,2,3" modelnum="0">
    <div class="authmodel authmodel_0 blueColorContainer">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class="marbom6 usernameContainer">
        <p class="pContainer authinputwidth">
          <label></label>
          <input id="username" value="Account" emptytip="Account" type="text" class="frm-input"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="marbom6 passwordContainer" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
        <p class="center pContainer authinputwidth">
          <label></label>
          <input id="password" value="Password" emptytip="Password" type="text" class="frm-input"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="rmbPwdContainer" style="display: none;margin: 0 auto;width: 270px;">
        <p class="center yaHei" style="text-align:left;padding-left: 24px;">
          <input id="rememberPwd" name="rememberPwd" type="checkbox" savetime="14" onclick="selectRememberPwd()" class="remPwdInp">Remember password</p>
      </div>
      <div class="validcodeContainer authenticationcodeContainer" style="margin-top: 10px; display: block;">
        <p class="pContainer authinputwidth">
          <input id="validCode" value="Verification code" type="text" class="frm-input" onkeydown="subLoginCheck()" data-type="" style="" emptytip="Verification code" validcodecomplex="2" validcodelength="4"></p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-top: 5px; text-align: center">

        <input id="loginBtn" type="button" value="Log In" class="frm-button borderRadius4" style="background-color: #95F4FF; border-color: #95F4FF;" onclick="login()"></p>

      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to show login form on the top of cloud background ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of the form  :)

Something like this

```
#authloginContainer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /*To hide the horizontal scroller appearing during the animation*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

#clouds {
  padding: 100px 0;
  background: #c9dbe9;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
  background: -linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
}

#authloginContainer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
}


/*Time to finalise the cloud shape*/

.cloud {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 200px;
  -moz-border-radius: 200px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.cloud:before,
.cloud:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 10px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.cloud:after {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  top: -55px;
  left: auto;
  right: 15px;
}


/*Time to animate*/

.x1 {
  -webkit-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
}


/*variable speed, opacity, and position of clouds for realistic effect*/

.x2 {
  left: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
  opacity: 0.6;
  /*opacity proportional to the size*/
  /*Speed will also be proportional to the size and opacity*/
  /*More the speed. Less the time in 's' = seconds*/
  -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
}

.x3 {
  left: -250px;
  top: -200px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0.8;
  /*opacity proportional to the size*/
  -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

.x4 {
  left: 470px;
  top: -250px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
  transform: scale(0.75);
  opacity: 0.75;
  /*opacity proportional to the size*/
  -webkit-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
}

.x5 {
  left: -150px;
  top: -150px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0.8;
  /*opacity proportional to the size*/
  -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
  0% {
    margin-left: 1000px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1000px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
  0% {
    margin-left: 1000px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1000px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
  0% {
    margin-left: 1000px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="clouds">
  <div class="cloud x1"></div>
  <!-- Time for multiple clouds to dance around -->
  <div class="cloud x2"></div>
  <div class="cloud x3"></div>
  <div class="cloud x4"></div>
  <div class="cloud x5"></div>
</div>

<!-- ************  This is my login form  ************ -->
<div id="authloginContainer">
  <div class="authloginTabContent" authpluginarray="1,2,3" modelnum="0">
    <div class="authmodel authmodel_0 blueColorContainer">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class="marbom6 usernameContainer">
        <p class="pContainer authinputwidth">
          <label></label>
          <input id="username" value="Account" emptytip="Account" type="text" class="frm-input"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="marbom6 passwordContainer" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
        <p class="center pContainer authinputwidth">
          <label></label>
          <input id="password" value="Password" emptytip="Password" type="text" class="frm-input"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="rmbPwdContainer" style="display: none;margin: 0 auto;width: 270px;">
        <p class="center yaHei" style="text-align:left;padding-left: 24px;">
          <input id="rememberPwd" name="rememberPwd" type="checkbox" savetime="14" onclick="selectRememberPwd()" class="remPwdInp">Remember password</p>
      </div>
      <div class="validcodeContainer authenticationcodeContainer" style="margin-top: 10px; display: block;">
        <p class="pContainer authinputwidth">
          <input id="validCode" value="Verification code" type="text" class="frm-input" onkeydown="subLoginCheck()" data-type="" style="" emptytip="Verification code" validcodecomplex="2" validcodelength="4"></p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-top: 5px; text-align: center">

        <input id="loginBtn" type="button" value="Log In" class="frm-button borderRadius4" style="background-color: #95F4FF; border-color: #95F4FF;" onclick="login()"></p>

      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```